# Boost version of Qt qglobal.h

Tags: c++, qt, boost, shared-libraries, qtcore

When using **Qt Creator** to create a library, it automatically generates a global header in which it defines the export symbols macro. This is an example code:

```
#ifndef LIB_GLOBAL_HPP
#define LIB_GLOBAL_HPP

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(LIB)
#  define LIB_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define LIB_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // LIB_GLOBAL_HPP
```

Is it possible to achieve the same platform independency using only the **Boost** library?
I'd like to use Qt Creator without depending on Qt library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your snippet does not seem to be complete, as that is not enough definition for a stable library, this seems to be possible by boost, too, by almost applying one-by-one mapping, i.e. just different names:

```
...
#if defined(BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK) || defined(BOOST_FOO_DYN_LINK)
# if defined(BOOST_FOO_SOURCE)
#   define BOOST_FOO_DECL BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT
# else
#   define BOOST_FOO_DECL BOOST_SYMBOL_IMPORT
# endif
#else
# define BOOST_FOO_DECL
#endif
...
```

Please note that it also contains the additional logic that I was referring above; without that, it is not really a complete cross-platform solution. For further details, please refer to the boost documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_for_libraries_with_separate_source_code.macros_controlling_shared_library_symbol_visibility).

Comment: I assure you my snippet is complete. Maybe there's a lot under the hood in the included `<QtCore/qglobal.h>`

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: your snippet does not deal with static builds. Please check [this](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/62dfdeb3642250bdb642dbf607a8c7b95e57835e:src/serialport/qserialportglobal.h#L51) source code out in QtSerialPort that we put in place a while ago. So, it is complete so long as you do not provide static builds for your users, but I am not sure whether that is a good idea.

Comment: ok sorry, that came out the QtCreator, it must be indended only for shared library

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: yeah, I trust you that you pasted what QtCreator generates. I probably was not clear enough: I blame QtCreator unless if there is an option to create this for a library that is meant to be used shared as well as static.